# Mathematical symbols not displaying in comments

Tags: bug, android-app, mathjax

Mathematical visualisations (not sure how these should be described, is there a better noun?) are not displaying correctly for me on the stack exchange app.

As you can see in the screenshot, they are being displayed exactly as entered, rather than being parsed and displayed the way the author intended.

This only occurs in comments on all sites. They show fine in questions and answers. They also appear fine in my browser (chrome mobile).

This has been the case for as long as I've used the app, but only just decided to report it here.

The app has no pending updates
Device: HTC 10
OS: Android 6.0.1

Is there anything I can do to remedy this or is it a bug?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for that link, I struggled to search as I was unsure what to call it. That does solve my problem, but it opens another query of why it's not enabled by default for all comments. One person suggested a speed issue but surely not, that was two years ago, we must be able to render some graphical symbols by now